# Creating and executing a script

Tags: scripting

Given the task:
Using head and tail, write a command to extract the second section of a file (i.e. the data section).

*I have figured out that: `tail -n 52 (path) | head -n 51` , will give me the correct head and tail command to extract this section.

Turn this into an executable script called extractdata. Then, using find and extractdata, write a command to get the second section of all .csv files in the month directories, and place the output into a file called polls.csv.

*So far I have figured out how to do the following,
vim extractdata

within extractdata:

```
#!/bin/sh
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#A script used to extract the second section of a file (i.e. the data section)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------


echo "Hello $USER."


tail -n 52 $1 | head -n 51
```

I am confused on what to do next, and how I would even go about executing this script. I changed the permissions using chmod 755 to make it an executable file but I don't know what comes next in this process.

**(EDIT)**: I have figured out how to run the script I created and it works as intended using the following command:

./extractdata /filepath/file.csv

***I am now stuck on how to get this section for ALL .csv files in the month directories, and place them into a file called polls.csv***

**(EDIT)**: Adding > polls.csv to my extractdata script saves my head and tail command to my polls.csv as intended. Now I just need to figure out how to execute this command for all .csv files in the filepath directory.

*(UPDATE): Is there some way I can add a loop into the script that will handle my problem of adding all .csv files extracted data to the polls.csv file?*

Comment: Did you had a look at the `find` tool? Search for some examples, try it out (first without `extractdata`), then maybe read `man find`. In particular, have a look at the `ACTIONS` section in `man find`.

Comment: Or, more likely for an intro class (as this seems to be), globs.

Comment: Hello yes this is an intro class, however its been pretty much self taught at this point. I have figured out how to use the find command how to find all .csv files already. The command would be: find -name "*.csv", however I do not know how to use my command to extract for all, I simply know how to do a single .csv file as stated above. I for sure don't know how to place them into a file called polls.csv using a script. (Also thank you for your quick replies and feedback)

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -iname '*.csv' | xargs -I {} tail -n 52 "{}" \| head -n 51 > polls.csv
```

Though you should likely be using grep instead of head and tail.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this without the benefit of a script using find's -exec feature:

```
for i in $(ls months)
do
find . -name \*.csv -exec tail -n 52 {} | head -n 51 >> /absolutePath/polls.csv \;
done
```

Comment: While this is helpful, I am specifically trying to do it the way in the original post. Ideally I'm looking to use the extractdata script I've created and somehow incorporate a find command to extract the section of data(using the head and tail methods) and then save them to a polls.csv file. I am stumped on the part of using find and extractdata and how to make these two commands save into a polls.csv file.

Comment: Pro tip:  if someone is trying to help you, don't downvote their comment.